# Select data from multiple tables in same query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull all categories for a blog post when the blog is loaded.  I have 2 tables for categories, one for the categories themselves and another that lists which categories are assigned to which blog post.

the MySQL command I have is

```
SELECT `category_name`, `category_slug` FROM `blog_categories`, `blog_post_categories` WHERE `blog_categories.category_id` = `blog_post_categories.category_id` AND `blog_post_categories.post_id` = 1
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
Unknown column 'blog_categories.category_id' in 'where clause'
```

The two tables are as such:

blog_categories has columns category_id, category_name and category_slug
blog_post_categories has columns id, post_id and category_id

Comment: Do not use comma-join syntax. And you shouldn't need backticks on properly qualified columns (such as these are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backticts are not in proper place should be as

```
SELECT `category_name`, 
`category_slug` 
FROM 
`blog_categories`, `blog_post_categories` 
WHERE `blog_categories`.`category_id` = `blog_post_categories`.`category_id` 
AND `blog_post_categories`.`post_id` = 1
```

Comment: Abhik, thank you so much.  Still a noob with sql so this helps alot. Will accept as soon as am able to.